# Is there an English translation of Kuratowski's theorem on forbidden minors of planar graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, translation

Is there an English translation of Kuratowski's proof about planar graphs?

Comment: You want a translation of his proof, or *a* proof?

Comment: I am interested in the translation (mostly).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case you are asking for the original paper "Sur le problème des courbes gauches en Topologie" by Kuratowski where he first proves his characterization of planar graphs, then a translation by J.Jaworowski can be found in "Graph Theory, Łagów", 1981, M. Borowiecki, J. W. Kennedy and M. M. Sysło. It is the proceedings of a conference held in Łagów, dedicated to the memory of K.Kuratowski.

Comment: Here are links to the French original and to the English translation (by Jaworowski) published in those proceedings.  http://www.springerlink.com/content/7021318369w65376/ http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm15/fm15126.pdf


Answer (score 3):

Kuratowski's theorem is set as an exercise in Ch. 5 of *Combinatorial Problems and Exercises* by Lovasz. The problem is given as follows:

Let G be a minimal non-planar graph with all vertices of degree at least 3. Then:

1. G is 3-connected. (This is straightforward; supposing otherwise and removing the cutset we can get a planar embedding of G.)
2. G contains a cycle with a chord. (Provided hint: Consider a maximum path.)
3. G is isomorphic to one of $K_5$, $K_{3, 3}$.
4. Conclude Kuratowski's theorem from part 3.

The proof is on pp. 299-301, which fortunately are all viewable in the [Google Books preview](http://books.google.com/books?id=e99fXXYx9zcC).

Answer (score 0):

You might just want to read Jim Belk's [excellent exposition](http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2007/07/09/graph-minor-theory-part-4/) at the Everything Seminar.

Comment: I believe his name is Jim Belk.